# How to extract a json value from a nested json string with Databricks sql

Tags: sql, arrays, json, databricks

Using Databricks SQL and trying to extract a nested json value 'instanceId' from cloudtrail logs ingested as a string. Data looks like:

```
select 
    requestparameters:instancesSet.items as items,
    typeof(items),
    schema_of_json(items) as schema,
    items.instanceId as instanceId
from cloudtrail;
```

| items | typeof | schema | instanceId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [{"instanceId":"14b6a528b915b3c0270e0174982e5ed78052eafd"}] | string | ARRAY<STRUCT<instanceId: STRING>> | null |
| [{"instanceId":"14b6a528b915b3c0270e0174982e5ed78052eafd.flaws.cloud"}] | string | ARRAY<STRUCT<instanceId: STRING>> | null |
| [{"instanceId":"14b6a528b915b3c0270e0174982e5ed78052eafd"}] | string | ARRAY<STRUCT<instanceId: STRING>> | null |

How can I directly adress and extract instanceId above using `items.instanceId` syntax? Tried with the below but get a schema error (direct invocation of `schema_of_json` or not gives the same error).

```
select 
from_json(requestparameters:instancesSet.items, 
           schema_of_json(items)) as items,
items:instanceId
from cloudtrail;
```

> '[INVALID_SCHEMA.NON_STRING_LITERAL] The input schema
> "lateralAliasReference(schema)" is not a valid schema string. The
> input expression must be string literal and not null.'

Comment: Since it shows up as ARRAY<STRUCT> - maybe consider exploding it first before extracting ?

Comment: something like `SELECT col.instanceId from EXPLODE(requestparameters:instancesSet.items)` - Just an example - might slightly change...